# mysql_affected_rows doesn't display message

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to display the affected rows, but for some reason it doesn't work.  when I run this code below, PHP's mysql_affected_rows() doesn't display anything. any suggestions

This is what i have:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
require 'connect4.php';
require 'security2.php';

$records = array();

if(isset($_POST)){
if(isset($_POST['first_name'],$_POST['id'])){
    $first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
    $id = trim($_POST['id']);

    if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($id)){
        $delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM people WHERE first_name = ? AND id = ?');
        $delete->bind_param('si',$first_name,$id);
        if($delete->execute()){
            echo $db->affected_rows. '<br>';
            header('location: index.php');
            die();
        }
    }else{
        echo 'something went wrong';
    }
}
}

if($results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM people')){
if($results->num_rows){
    while($row=$results->fetch_object()){
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    $results->free();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You tagged this `mysqli` yet you're using a `mysql_*` based function `mysql_affected_rows`

Comment: Seriously, questions mixing mysql_* and mysqli_ are so common, that should be awarded some dedicated tag: `mixing-mysql-mysqli`. ]

Comment: I am sorry, but I am new to php, i thought i can use both mysql and mysqli

Comment: Have you tried using mysqli_error or any of the other error functions?, mysql or mysqli whichever you are using

Answer (score 0):

Are you seriously mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions? You seem to use an OO API so it can only be `mysqli`. You can't mix the two.

This is the function you need: [mysqli_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/mysqli_affected_rows) or the `$mysqli->affected_rows` property.

Comment: "Are you seriously mixing mysql and mysqli functions?" ... at least the name is appropriate.

Comment: When i use $mysqli->affected_rows it still doesn't display anything

Comment: @KarishKarish `$mysqli` has to be the name of your mysqli connection obviously.

Comment: i know that i am using $db->affected_rows still doesn't work @CodeAngry

Comment: @KarishKarish Make sure the variable is in scope.